# Bluetooth LE Application Architecture

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm making my first Bluetooth LE application and need some advice on how to approach.

I need to have device such as a laptop (Windows, Linux, OSX, doesn't matter), track when devices (iOS and Android) come in Bluetooth LE range. The devices will be running an app that uses BT LE.  Each mobile device app will have a unique id (maybe a user id) that the laptop will collect.  I need this to happen without user interaction. That's it.

Which one should the peripheral and central should be?
Should the laptop be the central in this application?
I've also seen a GATT server used in Bluetooth applications.  Would it make more sense to use a GATT server than a peripheral and central?

Answer (score 1):

I am currently building an open source block based wrapper for `Core Bluetooth`.

I would use the laptop as the `Central Manager` that will listen out for all peripherals.

The iDevice will be the `Peripheral Manager` broadcasting itself and it's services & characteristics.

Sadly I have no experience with developing for windows and BLE but I have my framework working on both iOS and OSX and I have no problem sending or discovering each other.

With regards to a unique ID on iOS when you make a peripheral you broadcast with a `CBUUID`. This can be used to uniquely identify a peripheral as it is a GUID.

For all this to happen the app needs to be running in the background or the broadcasting of the peripheral will be terminated.

Comment: Thanks.  The unique id would be something stored inside the iOS app.  Could that be sent to the peripheral without user interaction?  Do you have any suggestions for sample code or tutorials to get started if I was to use iOS as the peripheral and OSX as the central?

Comment: If the iDevice has the app open broadcasting a service with the characteristic being an ID then yes, the Central Manager should be able to discover the peripheral, connect to it and the read its values providing that the characteristic dose not need any authentication. Meaning the characteristic has not been encrypted if it has then the user has to pair to the central manger for it to get the value.

Comment: Like I said. I'm working on a framework that aims to make it easier to read and send data over BLE. Once I have opened sourced it I'll post a link.

Comment: This approach is good if I'm using only iOS.  From what I've seen, Android doesn't allow the app to be a peripheral only central.

Comment: Interesting what you brought up about authentication.  I need the unique ID to be exchanged quickly without user interaction but I also want to keep it private in this application.  Pairing isn't an option if it requires the user to accept.

Comment: If you need to protect the ID, you should encrypt it but this would require pair. In iOS you set characteristic properties. https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCharacteristic_Class/translated_content/CBCharacteristic.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011286-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2 Sadly I do not know what the same is for android. If you don't encrypt the characteristic and hash the data would that not give you what you want?

Comment: Would the pair require user interaction?  There could be several peripherals in proximity of the central and the central needs to collect every peripheral id that comes into proximity.  So if 5 people walk into the proximity of the central at one time, I need the central to get each ID from the peripheral apps within a few seconds.  That sounds possible without pairing. If the unique id needs to be kept secure between the iOS app and the central this might require pairing which will take longer than the time needed.  Thanks a lot for helping explain this.

Comment: If you paired the two together this would need user interaction. An alert will show to the user and they will have to choose pair or cancel. But a pair is only needed for a characteristic that is encrypted/protected. In order for your central manager to read this ID the app on the device will be broadcast the characteristic on a set CBUUID. Your central manager will listen for all possible peripherals and when it discovers one it should automatically connect and then work down the service to the known characteristic CBUUID. Then read it and there you go :-)

Comment: Ok it's much clearer now.  The way you explained it will work as long as I don't care if the ID is public.  I still want to protect the ID without pairing but I don't think it's possible.  I thought maybe switching the roles so the iOS devices are centrals and the laptop is the peripheral.  Then the iOS devices are scanning for the laptop peripheral and they only send the ID when they find it.  I don't know if it's possible to push the ID from the central to the peripheral?  That might not protect the ID anyway because it's still public.

Comment: @user3380025 If you wanna go the reverse (i.e. iOS as Central, OSX as Peripheral), you could setup a write characteristic on the OSX. Sequence goes: 1) iOS constantly scans, 2) OSX within range, iOS detects the peripheral, connects, discovers services, discovers characteristics, finds write characteristic 4) iOS writes unique ID to OSX, 5) iOS disconnects. If you want security, add encryption which requires pairing only once, or you could devise some sort of hashing algorithm so that the value transmitted by iOS can only be interpreted by OSX.

Comment: @Yazid thanks.  I think the reverse might work too.  It's good to know you can write in both directions using a characteristic.

Answer (score 0):

I have now released the 1st part of my Core Bluetooth Manager. V1.0 only has the Central manager part for now, but the Peripheral Manager part is in development.

You can download it at https://github.com/steprescott/SCPCoreBluetoothManager

Answer (score 0):

Please note, You can simply go and checkout https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/LGBluetooth

Here are awesome examples of using LGBluetooth (note: even connection is handled by framework)

**read operation**

```
    [LGUtils readDataFromCharactUUID:@"f045"
                             serviceUUID:@"5ec0"
                              peripheral:peripheral
                              completion:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                                  NSLog(@"Data : %s Error : %@", (char *)[data bytes], error);
                              }];
```

**write operation**

```
        int8_t dataToWrite = 0xFF;
        [LGUtils writeData:[NSData dataWithBytes:&dataToWrite length:sizeof(dataToWrite)]
               charactUUID:@"cef9"
               serviceUUID:@"5ec0"
                peripheral:peripheral completion:^(NSError *error) {
                    NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
                }];
```